# Validation accuracy have an almost good accuracy but loss function is high too

Tags: deep-learning, loss-function, accuracy, overfitting, validation

Based on my project, I find a little problem there with the statement like this.

I want to make model with neural networks for text dataset. Then I use Pad Sequence for my text and Array for the labels. I have 3 labels before after I change it with 
 `df=df[df.labels != "Neutral"]` 
 and now I just have 2 labels (means Pos and Neg) then I use array for that.

When I also want handle imbalance data, using undersampling then splitting the data with train test split. So, my model using Dense is 2, Sigmoid for Activation and use Binary Crossentropy for Loss. There I get problems.

My accuracy is good with the loss function but my validation accuracy and the loss function not good. I think it's gonna be overfit

So, what can I do to handle or make sure for next step to handle this problem? Or can someone tell me what's my fault?

Comment: Your question is not very clear I'm afraid. As far as I understand you're doing binary classification, so you should probably evaluate with precision/recall/f-score. Also I'd suggest doing a simple baseline model (e.g. decision tree) before using a complex neural network (more likely to overfit). Finally it's unlikely that resampling would really help, be careful to evaluate properly on the original distribution.

Comment: @Erwan , Thanks in advance for your suggestions, I'll try that first. Maybe I should fix, which class am I using to create the model. Then, when creating the model, I can fix the activation and loss functions appropriate